# Improperly handled exception thrown from IDataServiceQueryProvider.GetPropertyValue?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

This question pertains to a WCF data service with custom providers. Until recently, we have not had any problems with exceptions thrown by implementations of IDataServiceQueryProvider or IDataServiceUpdateProvider. The current issue we are facing is that exceptions thrown by IDataServiceQueryProvider.GetPropertyValue are not being handled correctly. For example, this request:

```
http://localhost:52788/NorthwindCustomers.svc/Customers('ALFKI')
```

With this implementation:

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object target, ResourceProperty resourceProperty)
{
    throw new DataServiceException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request!");
}
```

Results in:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><entry xml:base="http://localhost:52788/NorthwindCustomers.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><id>http://localhost:52788/NorthwindCustomers.svc/Customers('ALFKI')</id><category term="NorthwindModel.Customer" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="Customer" href="Customers('ALFKI')" /><m:error><m:code /><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Bad request!</m:message></m:error>`

Whereas the same exception thrown from other methods, such as this:

```
public IQueryable GetQueryRootForResourceSet(ResourceSet resourceSet)
{
    throw new DataServiceException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request!");
}
```

Result in the expected:

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code></code><message xml:lang="en-US">Bad request!</message></error>`

I have reproduced this with a bare-bones service and custom providers to eliminate the possibility of the problem being caused by our production implementation.

Why does the framework create a response with the correct status code and body for exceptions thrown by all implementations of IDataServiceQueryProvider and IDataServiceUpdateProvider methods except for GetPropertyValue?